# Why is https always used with www subdomain?

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, subdomain

I have been trying to reason this out, but haven't been able to. All the https websites that I have surfed use www subdomain. Is it possible to have something like https://foo.com. If yes, then why is it so rare or uncommon?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be about programming. Your question may be on-topic at another site, such as [webmasters.se] or [su]; check their respective sites' help pages to learn what is and isn't on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Technically**, there is no reason why HTTPS cannot be used without a www subdomain. Ex: https://mail.google.com.

You might be wrong in your observation. After all, how many of the millions of domains do we get to see.:)